# reading xml with linq (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

how do I read the following xml document?

My code is :

```
var vb =
    (from vbs in XMLDoc.Descendants("Response").Descendants("Records ")
    select new
        {
           ref = vbs.Element("ref").Value
        }).ToList();
```

XML Document:

```
<Response>
  <Msg>
       <Code>30</Code>
    <Query/>
  </Msg>
<Rec>
    <Records price="1989" no="838976" ref="1927A64FF6B03527E5BFD8424F647848005143DB" query="00"/>
</Rec>
</Response>
```

Comment: What's going wrong? What (if anything) does the code return?

Comment: For starters, `"Records "` should probably be `"Records"`.

Comment: I just want the lines of REC, how can i do?

Comment: i cannot bind to GridView, 
seems to:
<Rec>
    <Records price="1989" no="838976" ref="1927A64FF6B03527E5BFD8424F647848005143DB" query="00"/>
</Rec>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Records "` should be `"Records"`, and your call to `Element()` in the anonymous class member initializer should be `Attribute()` since you are reading an attribute, which is not an element.

```
var vb =
    (from vbs in XMLDoc.Descendants("Response").Descendants("Records")
    select new
        {
           ref = (string)vbs.Attribute("ref")
        }).ToList();
```

The conversion to `string` is preferred when reading attributes, IMO, because it will return `null` when the attribute cannot be found.  If you use `vbs.Attribute("ref").Value` instead, then you will cause a `NullReferenceException` if the attribute does not exist.